How to get full pager in media_library_opener
When I want to select media in D10 I get an overlay view with a mini pager. I have lots of images. To select an older image I have to go to page 2, 3, 4, ... I know the image is at page 16 or 17.
I like to change the pager to the full pager, but I cannot find where / how.
Is a solution available?

The Media Library widget is built with a Drupal View. To modify the View display corresponding to the media library widget:

Browse to /admin/structure/views/view/media_library/edit/widget.
Under the pager options, select "Full" instead of "Mini". Adjust
other settings as needed.

This will enable a full pager in the widget.

thanks. I changed the pager in that view before I wrote my question, Now I did update the pager options also and it works.
